# Router and switch subnet conflict

Tags: networking, router, switch, subnet

I have a router and switch in my home network. I can access the router via the IP 192.168.0.1. I recently plugged an 8-port switch into it (port 1 from router to port 8 on switch) and things were working fine. If I plugged a computer into any other port on the switch, I would get an IP on the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet and the internet would work.

At some point I believe the switch got unplugged accidentally, so I plugged it back in. I'm not sure if that was the source of the issues, but since then I have had basically no internet connection when plugged into the switch. I also can only access the modem sometimes via 192.168.0.1; other times that IP gives me the switch GUI (just by refreshing the browser a few seconds or minutes apart).

I can fix this by changing the subnet on the switch GUI to something like 192.168.1.0/24, but this feels unnecessarily complicated. Also, that subnet seems to get reset if the switch is ever powered off again.

Possibly I have to power on devices in a certain order? Or maybe plug in cables in a certain order after everything is powered on?

Comment: Guess: The configuration of the switch got messed up somehow. If you are using at as a simple layer 2 switch, no extra features, you **don't have to tell the switch anything about subnets**. All such configurations in there (and possibly others) are bogus. There are no IP addresses on layer 2. And it's impossible to say what exactly is wrong without having access to your switch, and seeing the complete configuration.

Comment: @dirkt: Switches of course can act as hosts and have IP addresses for management purposes. So OP just has an ordinary IP conflict between two hosts (router and switch mgmt). Maybe the switch has a separate "save settings" function, or maybe its NVRAM fried?

Comment: You have IP duplication - both router's LAN IP and switch's inner IP are 192.168.0.1. That is a serious addressing mistake. Recommendations: 1. Detach switch; 2. Access router and change its DHCP lease range to, for example, 192.168.0.16-254; 3. Set static IP 192.168.0.3/24 to PC, connect it to switch and access it; 4. Change switch's IP to 192.168.0.2; 5. Connect switch to router back, revert PC to DHCP. Do not forget to save the configuration of the switch! If not, it will revert back when power off/on.

Comment: The reason it changes from time to time almost certainly has to do with the ARP cache. As @Akina pointed out, both the switch and router have the same IP, so your PC can only have an entry for one at a time. When the ARP entry expires, your PC will reach out by broadcast and the device that wins the race gets the spot in your ARP table until the entry expires again.